# A part of my PHP code appears as text in the page

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

This is my code.. The problem is that the code after the '>' in if(mysql_affected_rows()>0) id displayed as plain text in the webpage.. Please help..

```
<?php
session_start();
if( isset( $_POST[reg] ) )
{
    $name = $_POST[n1];
    $age = $_POST[a1];
    $gen = $_POST[r1];
    $phno = $_POST[phno1];
    $email = $_POST[email1];
    $pin = $_POST[pin1];
    $user = $_POST[u1];
    $pas = $_POST[pass];
    $pas1 = $_POST[pass1];
    $i = $_POST[i1];              

    include( "connect.php" );

    $q = "INSERT INTO reg VALUES('0', '$name', '$age', '$gen', '$phno', '$email', '$pin', '$user', '$pas')";
    mysql_query( $q ) or die( mysql_error() );

    if(mysql_affected_rows()>0)
    {
        header("location:index.php");                         
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please look into PDO or MySQLi instead of MySQL as it is now deprecated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like your PHP code is not being interpreted at all. If you look at the source code via the browser, do you see a `<?php` tag in there? This should not happen. If this is the case, your PHP code is not being recognized.

For example, looking at the source in Firefox, if you see something like this, something is wrong with how PHP is executed: [image of PHP code that isn't executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii5qc.png)

Any `<?php` tag that can be seen in the browser's source code is a problem.

---

By the way, be sure to put strings into quotes. You are using things like `$_POST[u1]` where it should be `$_POST["u1"]` or `$_POST['u1']`. Only [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php) should be used without quotes.

Comment: So what can I do to correct the situation? I've just started using PHP recently and this was part of a project to make a registration page..

Comment: What is the file extension?

Comment: Make sure that you put your code in .php files (not in .html) and that PHP code can be run. If you want to run it on your computer, you will need to install something like [xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)

Comment: the file extension is .php itself

Comment: What server are You using? It's local like XAMPP, Webserv etc?

Comment: Configure correctly, or reinstall. But that's out of SO's scope, you'd need to go to serverfault to get help with that.

Comment: @hotinlavacoolinjava But then the entry page that comes with Wamp at `http://localhost/` doesn't display properly either, right?

Comment: @ljacqu Nope there's nothing wrong with the entry page.. When I checked the source code in Google Chrome, the code for PHP is in green  right upto that '>' and then its like regular text.

Comment: @hotinlavacoolinjava If you actually see PHP code when looking in the source code, something is wrong and PHP is not being executed.

Comment: Would it help if I showed you the whole code including the html?

Comment: @hotinlavacoolinjava No. Regardless of what your PHP code says, _it is not being interpreted_. This could be a) you are not viewing the file via `http://localhost/...` in your browser, b) something is wrong with Wamp, c) there's some character/encoding problem and the starting tag is not being recognized.

Comment: @hotinlavacoolinjava I would suggest creating a new .php file in the same folder and just adding `<?php phpinfo();` and to see if that is being run. If yes, gradually copy the PHP code of your file into it.

Comment: @ljacqu It's working now. It was the first problem. Thanks man.